# How to create dropdown in Excel using Angular

Tags: angular, excel

I want to create an excel sheet in angular that has in one of the cells an option for a dropdown

I tried using this code:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

generateExcel() {
    // Create a worksheet
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([
      ['Data Validation Example'],
      ['Select an option:'],
    ]);
  
    // Define the data validation (dropdown) for a specific cell (e.g., A3)
    worksheet['!dataValidations'] = [{
      sqref: 'A3',
      formula1: '"Option 1,Option 2,Option 3"',
      showDropDown: true,
    }];
  
    // Create a workbook
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {
      Sheets: { 'Sheet 1': worksheet },
      SheetNames: ['Sheet 1'],
    };
  
    // Generate the Excel file
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    const data: Blob = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
  
    // Save the file
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'excel_with_dropdown.xlsx');
  }
```

but id does not create the dropdown for me